# How to store hash-like objects in a PostgreSQL database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, hstore

First, a bit of info. My Rails app has a model called `Neo` which in turn has attributes `observed_at`, `ra` and `dec`.

However, I now found that I need to store sets of this data (in Python-like fashion it would be a ***list of tuples***.) In Ruby, that would probably be a list of lists.

How can I achieve this? I don't mind using `hstore` but I would prefer not to as the docs on that are few.

Comment: The simplest way would be in a table of four columns--three for "observed_at", "ra", and "dec", and a fourth column to store an identifier for the set. What data types are you using for those columns?

Comment: `observed_at` is obviously a date. `ra` and `dec` are both floats. Howver, each `Neo` has multiple sets of these.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the simpler [`serialize`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/serialize/class), instead of hstore.

Alternatively, you can create a model for these sets, then use `has_many` on Neo, and `belongs_to` on the new model.

Comment: The second option hit me right now. Thanks for the help anyway.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of serialized language-specific objects in databases. They're a major pain when you upgrade the language runtime or change the object structure, and they're immensely frustrating when you need to talk to the database with another language, a reporting engine, etc. A simple 1:m relationship is a much saner approach.

Answer (score 3):

As Guilherme Berger notes, a 1:many relationship is the typical way to model a "list of lists" ... or more precisely, a *set of sets*; to give it *order* you have to define some kind of ordering key in each sub-table.

Another option open to you when using PostgreSQL is to use a multi-dimensional array. Unfortunately Pg's arrays are a bit weird, in that a two-dimensional array is more like a matrix (ie: fixed dimensions) rather than a list of lists. If your sub-lists are the same length that's fine, but if they're variable and unbounded lengths arrays of arrays are not a good choice.

I'm mentioning this mostly for completeness's sake, and to explain that serializing language-specific objects in databases is *not* the right approach to take here. It'll be horrible the first time you have to update to a new major runtime release, change your object structure, or access the database from a different language or a reporting engine. I really don't recommend it.